# Opposite results using statsmodels and seaborn regplot

Tags: linear-regression, seaborn

I use regplot using the following code:

```
sns.regplot(x = "Year", y = "Data_Value", data = NOAA_TMAX_s );
```

and I obtain the following figure:

[image]

showing clearly that the trend is negative.

As seaborn does not provide the equation I calculate it by the following code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = NOAA_TMAX_s["Year"]
y = NOAA_TMAX_s["Data_Value"]
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()
print(results.summary())
```

and this is the output:

```
LS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:             Data_Value   R-squared:                       0.982
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.982
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 1.141e+06
Date:                Mon, 30 Mar 2020   Prob (F-statistic):               0.00
Time:                        20:13:08   Log-Likelihood:            -1.0576e+05
Df Residuals:                   20961   BIC:                         2.115e+05
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Year           0.1380      0.000   1068.387      0.000       0.138       0.138
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                      331.301   Durbin-Watson:                   0.456
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              387.614
Skew:                          -0.255   Prob(JB):                     6.77e-85
Kurtosis:                       3.428   Cond. No.                         1.00
==============================================================================
```

As I understand it, the result yields a positive highly significative coeficient.
I need some help to understand why both results are not coherent.

Comment: statsmodels does not add a constant by default, except when using formulas. You only have one parameter and no constant or intercept in the summary. see `add_constant` function and usage examples.

Comment: Adding the intercept  fixed the problem